# webpage content extraction error

Tags: python, html, findall

Web page code:

```
"caption": "~ I hate the idea of limitations ~\n
```

My code to extract comment:

```
caption = findall('"caption": "~(.+) ~\n ',web_page_contents)
```

When executed I get:

```
[]
```

I want to get the quote out of the webpage code.

Comment: Have you looked into using the beautiful soup module?  That's probably the best bet for getting content out of HTML.

Comment: Don't use regex to extract text from HTML. Use HTML parser of any kind, like mentioned Beautiful Soup.

Comment: I totally agree with the two other comments. Treating is as a problem with regular expressions, I'd ask if the space after \n in your pattern is there on purpose? If I remove it, the snipped above is matched by your reg. exp.